# Formular Url con variable de retorno en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Actualmente estoy tomando un proyecto en Django implementando la librería `Jinja2` ,la cual requiero realizar un hipervinculo que retorne una variable pero me esta dando error y no estoy seguro si sea por la sintaxis.

Template:

```
<a href="{{ url('ModificarStatus') orden.q_id }}" class="mybtn btn-warning btn-md colora " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Facturar"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-print ciconc"></span></a>
```

URL:

```
url(r'ModificarStatus/(?P<q_id>\d+)/$', ModificarStatus, name='ModificarStatus'),
```

Vista:

```
def ModificarStatus(request,q_id):
    orden=Transaction.objects.get(q=q_id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        statusM=StatusForm(instance=orden)
    else:
        statusM=StatusForm(request.POST,instance=orden)
        if statusM.is_valid():
            statusM.save()
        return redirect('/admin/ordenes')
    return render (request,'admin_prueba_status1.html',{'statusM':statusM})
```

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En django una url en platilla la identifica de esta forma

```
<a href="{% url 'Mi_app:name_mi_url' orden.q_id %}" class="mybtn btn-warning btn-md colora " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Facturar"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-print ciconc"></span></a>
```

A la url le falta

> ^

```
 url(r'^ModificarStatus/(?P<q_id>\d+)/$', ModificarStatus, name='ModificarStatus'),
```

Comment: gracias amigo por su repuesta, pero el circunflejo  no era el error pue sel circunflejo ^ solo me indica desde  donde inicia la cadena de caracteres del url ,pude modificar la sintaxis de manera correcta utilizando la libreria ninja2 quedando asi 
                                    <a href="{{ url('ModificarStatus' , order.q) }}" class="mybtn btn-warning btn-md colora " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Facturar"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-print ciconc"></span></a>
 pero aun me da otro error :  
No module named '201716304040'

Comment: El error le da renderizando la plantilla admin-orders.html en la linea 67. ¿Que hay en esa línea?